# Yii2 set config file for module

Tags: php, structure, yii2

How can i create my config in Yii2? and return in it for example
$new = 'new'
and then use it in other class?
My structure

```
 Module
    MyModule
      config (directory)
        config.php (here must be $new = 'new')
      function (directory)
        MyFunc ( here i need use variable from config)
```

Thanks for help!
code from

```
    <?php
    namespace module\MyModule\function;

    class MyFunc
  {
   private static function func()
    {
   here i need to get $new from config
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could have a look to the links in my own [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317208/yii2-config-params-vs-constants)

Answer (score 0):

set config file in Module class like below:

```
class Module extends \yii\base\Module    {
    public function init(){
        parent::init();
        \Yii::configure($this, require __DIR__ . '/config.php');
}
```

your config file like this:

```
return [
   'params' => [ 
       'test' => 'this is the test params'
   ],
   'components' => [
     // ...
   ],
];
```

accessing params in module:

```
\Yii::$app->getModule('MyModule')->params['test'];
```

Answer (score -2):

Why you config file in module inside? Put configFile in common config directory and this configuration will accassible in you app.