# Yii2: Config params vs. const/define

Tags: php, configuration, config, yii2

When should I use what?

I have the option to define constants in the index.php entry script file like it is recommended in [Yii2 guide: constants](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html#defining-constants). Or I could use the params in the configuration - explained in [YII2 guide: params](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#params). Both are per application and not really global.

Currently, it seems to me that params are a bit less comfortable if I want to combine values like this:

```
define('SOME_URL',            'http://some.url');
define('SOME_SPECIALIZED_URL', SOME_URL . '/specialized');
```

Besides, accessing is bit more code (`Yii::$app->params['something']`) compared to constants.

So when should or could I use what?

*Small update*: in PHP 7 `define()` supports arrays as well, so the whole params structure can be configured as a constant. Probably better supported by IDEs.

Comment: I can't remember any specific recommendations about it. I personally prefer params. Advantages of constants: less code to write, IDE autocomplete support.

Comment: You can use constants to store only primitive values - numbers, strings, booleans etc. For complex data, you have to choose parameters (as you're not able to store arrays and objects in constants), and it's often necessary to organize your data in logical groups.

Comment: Also, when you use some deployment tools you can set different values for different deployment environments. The constants should be used when you only have the values, that are the same in every environment

Comment: Use Yii::$app->params if you need to use value any where. But if you will use value once then I recommend just constants. But remember in Yii::$app->params you can use enviroment variables like getenv('any_key');

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use the Yii application parameters. The main reason for this is the values held in these kind of parameters tend to change depending on the environment that the code is run in. So I will have a build system that runs (I use [Phing](https://www.phing.info)) and pulls in settings from a non-version controlled file such as build.properties.

So any dev database settings, dev domain settings, api sandbox addresses etc will be loaded in in my development environment and the correct production values will be used when a build is run on a live server.

If you were settings these values in some kind of php file, then tracking with version control becomes problematic because each time you build in your dev environment changes would be made to your index.php file. Someone might even end up committing these changes in by mistake.

So in summary, I would say if they are true constants - the same in any environment in which the code runs - they maybe a constant is fine. If these values might change, depending on where the code is run, then my preference is to place them in params and let your build system load them from a non-version controlled file.

Answer (score -1):

The main disadvantage (and advantage at the same time) of constants is that they're... constant. Once you set it, you can't change it. This is the only  thing that should matter here. You should use constants for values that should never change during execution, and params for everything else.

Constants may be a real PITA when you start writing tests for your app. It will show you that many things that you considered as constant are not really constant. At this point params are more flexible - you can easily change them or adjust at configuration level using merging of configuration arrays. Using constants may drive you into a trap of unconfigurable application that cannot be installed on different environment without modification of hardcoded constant.

> Besides, accessing is bit more code (`Yii::$app->params['something']`) compared to constants.

This is completely irrelevant. As a programmer you spend less than 5% of your time on actually writing a code. Additional 10 keystrokes will do not make any difference. You should always think about it in terms of readability. You write code once and read it hundreds of times, so it is much more important  how much time you will need to read and understand code than the time you spent on writing it. And using known conventions (and `Yii::$app->params` is one of them) makes your code easier to understand, especially for other programmers.

But if you really want to write less code, you can always create a wrapper function for short access to params.

```
function p($name) {
    return Yii::$app->params[$name];
}

echo p('my-param');
```

Comment: "The main disadvantage (and advantage at the same time) of constants is that they're... constant" that's why it is called CONFIG. Which must be constant... unlike settings

Comment: What is called "config" and what is the difference between settings? You're using some self-made terminology here, don't expect people will understand what you're talking about. Also note that there is a very little cases where some setting needs to be a constant and inability to change it in the same request may be a problem during testing.

Comment: Welcome to the IT world! https://wikidiff.com/configuration/setting

Comment: Did you read this definition? It does not look like IT-related. But even if, you can't treat app configuration as constant, hardcoding things like URLs is just asking for troubles and in a way it proves, that you don't have proper tests.

Comment: Configs [usally] are wrriten/stored only once, (like db stuff, app paths, error handling stuff...) when the application installed, or needs to get initialized, or set some base requirements. It also changes very rarely. Thats why it is stored in flat-files. Unlike settings/preferences which doesnt store infrastructure related stuff and changes day to day(like font size, color, etc...). Thats why they stored in db(usally). You dont have to mix them in one term, just cus you dont like it or cant understand their diff!

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub Please, read the OP's question before sharing your input, because it is completely unrelated to Yii 2 app config (no "settings", only "config", but you definitely cannot use constants exclusively, because config is not constant, you may need to change some values in the same request).

Comment: I'm COMMENTING about your answer, not OP's question. Goodluck!